# How to configure Visual Studio Code for Processing?

Tags: visual-studio-code, processing

I am creating projects in `Processing 3.5.3`. I don't like the Processing IDE and want to use Visual Studio Code instead. I couldn't find a helpful source online (most didn't have the full instructions).

I installed the Processing Language extension in Visual Studio Code. In order to configure it, I created a file named `Processing.pde`, opened it, and then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and typed `Create Task File`. I selected my workspace folder from the list in the Command Palette. I got a notification saying:

> `tasks.json` already exists. Overwrite it?

I clicked Yes, and got another notification saying

> Please add Processing to your path!

I have Processing in `E:\processing-3.5.3-windows64\processing-3.5.3`. I added this to the path variable (in System Variables) and tried again. But I got the notification again.

Am I adding the wrong path? How do I configure VSCode for Processing?

Comment: Are you trying to edit `.pde` files or `.java` files that use Processing as a library?

Comment: @KevinWorkman `.pde`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems figuring it out too. This [GitHub page](https://github.com/TobiahZ/processing-vscode#add-processing-to-path) helped.

Your path should end with `processing-java`, and use `\\` instead of `\`.

Example:

```
"processing.path": "C:\\Program Files\\processing-3.0.1\\processing-java",
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)! Ctrl + Shift + X

Go to **Preferences JSON**

> Ctrl + Shift + P
> *SEARCH **PREFERENCES JSON***
> Add This Into The JSON file

```
{"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
        ".pde": "cd $dir && mkdir $fileNameWithoutExt && cd $fileNameWithoutExt && copy $fullFileName ./ && processing-java --sketch=$dirWithoutTrailingSlash\\$fileNameWithoutExt  --run && rmdir $fileName && cd $dir && rmdir $fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
```

To Compile And Export, Use This Instead

```
{
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
        ".pde": "cd $dir && mkdir $fileNameWithoutExt && cd $fileNameWithoutExt && copy $fullFileName ./ && processing-java --sketch=$dirWithoutTrailingSlash\\$fileNameWithoutExt --output=\"$workspaceRoot\\output\" --force --variant=windows-amd64 --export  && processing-java --sketch=$dirWithoutTrailingSlash\\$fileNameWithoutExt  --run && rmdir $fileName && cd $dir && rmdir $fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
```

To Compile And Export Without Java, Use this instead

```
{
"code-runner.executorMapByFileExtension": {
        ".pde": "cd $dir && mkdir $fileNameWithoutExt && cd $fileNameWithoutExt && copy $fullFileName ./ && processing-java --sketch=$dirWithoutTrailingSlash\\$fileNameWithoutExt --output=\"$workspaceRoot\\output\" --force --variant=windows-amd64 --no-java --export  && processing-java --sketch=$dirWithoutTrailingSlash\\$fileNameWithoutExt  --run && rmdir $fileName && cd $dir && rmdir $fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
```

This is a very round about way of doing this process with the help of cmd commands, It is much easier to simply just use Processing IDE